# nodejs + jsdom, jQuery strange behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, serverside-javascript, jsdom

The code below is just a small snippet from my server.js file just to run the test provided by the jsdom documentation.

```
var window = jsdom.jsdom().createWindow();
jsdom.jQueryify(window, './jq.min.js' , function() {
  console.log('inside');
  window.$('body').append('<div class="testing">Hello World, It works</div>');
  console.log(window.$('.testing').text());
  console.log('end');
});
```

The output I get literally is just `inside` and then the server hangs and never returns. I've added a debug statement `console.log(window);` to see if the window object is truly being created, and I do end up with a fairly large output statement detailing the object's contents. One thing I did notice however is that the output does **not** show that `$` is a defined method of the `window` object and in fact, `console.log(window.$);` renders `undefined`.

I understand jsdom is still in dev mode, but is there something I'm missing here?

*Just as some background, I have tried several variations of the code, including using the `jsdom.env()` method and also building a document from existing HTML markup, neither of which rendered expected results either.*

Answer (score -1):

I hope this code snippet helps you:

```
createWindow = function(fn) {
    var window  = jsdom.jsdom().createWindow(),
        script = window.document.createElement('script');

    jsdom.jQueryify(window, function() {
        script.src = 'file://' + __dirname + '/some.library.js';
        script.onload = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 'complete') {
                fn(window);
            }
        }
    });
}

createWindow(function(window) {
    // Do your jQuery stuff:
    window.$('body').hide();
});
```

[from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987768/jquery-plugins-with-node-js)